# Offline install setuptools - Python3

Tags: python, linux, pip, package, offline

I'm trying to install setuptools offline in order to install cx_Oracle, as this one asks for the first in my offline machine and I keep getting this error after running this command:

python3.11 -m pip install setuptools-67.8.0.tar.gz

*ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel (from versions: none)*

*ERROR: No matching distribution found for wheel*

*WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip*

How could I install it, what could be happening?

In the end, installing an older version of wheel (38) and an older version of setuptools (67.7.2) I managed to install it.

Reading the comment, I tried to install oracledb, the version 1.3.1 but now I have the same problem when installing this one:

*ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=40.6.0 (from versions: none)*

*ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=40.6.0*

*WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip*

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: A couple of recommendations: (i) use the latest cx_Oracle version, now called python-oracledb, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a) (ii) update `pip` itself (iii) try different versions of setuptools?

Comment: @ChristopherJones finally, with an older version of wheel (38)I managed to install wheel and setuptools on an older version (67.7.2) But now I have another problem, I will update the post